# what's the conjugate of $i^{-\frac{1}{2}}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If a complex number is $A=a+bi$, then its conjugate is $\bar{A}=a-bi$.
What's more, the conjugate of $e^{i\theta}$ is $e^{-i\theta}$. Well, it is known to us.

Now, if a complex number is $i^{-\frac{1}{2}}$, what's its conjugate?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:  $i=e^{i\pi/2}\implies i^{-1/2}=e^{-i\pi/4}$

Answer (score 1):

The complex exponential is usually defined by the equation $a^b = \exp(b \log a)$. But you already know how to take the complex conjugate of a complex exponential.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot too much things.